# request() empty in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request, sec-fetch-site, sec-fetch-mode

I have a simple Laravel application, in which a third party is redirecting to a route from an external source.

This external site hits a very simple logout controller at `/saml/logout`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Saml;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Log;

class LogoutController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Entry point for SAML logout.
     * TODO: check if you need auth to go here.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('Response:', (array) request());
        Log::info('Response:', (array) $_REQUEST);
        Log::info('Response:', (array) $_GET);
        Log::info('Response:', (array) $_POST);
        Log::info('Response:', (array) $request->method());
    }
}
```

Here is the trace I can see:

[image]

So, according to this tracer its able to hit the URL and get a HTTP status of 200.

[image]

However, in my logs I get the following.

[image]

---

My question is, why am I getting nothing in my logs in regards to the request?

The only thing I can see that's slightly odd is that something called `Sec-Fetch-Dest` is set to iframe.

**An update given answers.**

Using `$request->all()` gives me nothing.

[image]

**A further update**

[image]

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: `request()` returns an instance of the request class not of the request data.

Comment: `GET .../saml/logout` - what are you expecting to see in the request?  There is nothing in either `$_GET` or `$_POST`, right?  Try `GET .../saml/logout?foo=bar`, log `$request->all();`.

Comment: I was expecting a SAML response under a variable like SamlRequest, but it appears to not be in the request. This is a decent theory because it could well be that this third party isn't sending anything.

Comment: The request is not the response. `$_GET` and `$_POST` and Laravel's `$request` are all related to the incoming request, sent by the browser.  The response is how the server responds to that request.

Comment: Apologies, that was poor wording in the logs. I understand. I just find it odd that this third party is claiming to be sending data, but if this were indeed the case, am I write in thinking at least one of the above would've picked it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try   `$request->all()`

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Log::info('Response:', $request->all());
}
```